# Sorting an array in tcl

Tags: arrays, sorting, arraylist, tcl

I have an array path unsorted

```
path(11,0) = susan susan_s1 0.0 peter peter_i_p1 0.0 peter peter_o_p1 0.0
path(2,0) = maria maria_s2 0.0 ted ted_i_p2 0.0 ted ted_o_p2 0.0
path(3,0) = maria maria_s3 0.0 ted ted_i_p3 0.0 ted ted_o_p3 0.0
path(0,0) = maria maria_s0 0.0 ted ted_i_p0 0.0 ted ted_o_p0 0.0
path(10,0) = susan susan_s0 0.0 peter peter_i_p0 0.0 peter peter_o_p0 0.0
path(1,0) = maria maria_s1 0.0 ted ted_i_p1 0.0 ted ted_o_p1 0.0
```

If I used lsort for (array names path) , I will get

```
path(0,0) = maria maria_s0 0.0 ted ted_i_p0 0.0 ted ted_o_p0 0.0
path(1,0) = maria maria_s1 0.0 ted ted_i_p1 0.0 ted ted_o_p1 0.0
path(10,0) = susan susan_s0 0.0 peter peter_i_p0 0.0 peter peter_o_p0 0.0
path(11,0) = susan susan_s1 0.0 peter peter_i_p1 0.0 peter peter_o_p1 0.0
path(2,0) = maria maria_s2 0.0 ted ted_i_p2 0.0 ted ted_o_p2 0.0
path(3,0) = maria maria_s3 0.0 ted ted_i_p3 0.0 ted ted_o_p3 0.0
```

However I would like to have the final file as followings:

```
path(0,0) = maria maria_s0 0.0 ted ted_i_p0 0.0 ted ted_o_p0 0.0
path(1,0) = maria maria_s1 0.0 ted ted_i_p1 0.0 ted ted_o_p1 0.0
path(2,0) = maria maria_s2 0.0 ted ted_i_p2 0.0 ted ted_o_p2 0.0
path(3,0) = maria maria_s3 0.0 ted ted_i_p3 0.0 ted ted_o_p3 0.0
path(10,0) = susan susan_s0 0.0 peter peter_i_p0 0.0 peter peter_o_p0 0.0
path(11,0) = susan susan_s1 0.0 peter peter_i_p1 0.0 peter peter_o_p1 0.0
```

So how to do it ?

either a) sorting the index of path
or having keyword list (maria, susan) to obtain the final file

Thx, Maria

Answer (score 2):

Try the `-dictionary` option to `lsort`.

```
lsort -dictionary [array names path]
# -> 0,0 1,0 2,0 3,0 10,0 11,0
```

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm)

Comment: This is a great solution, since it will also sort by the numbers after the `,` as a subsidiary key. But what it won't do is handle negative numbers right as it treats `-` as a separator, not a minus symbol. (For lots of uses, that doesn't matter.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: I always try to avoid thinking about negative things.

Answer (score -1):

hmmm...

```html
path(11,0) = susan susan_s1 0.0 peter peter_i_p1 0.0 peter peter_o_p1 0.0
path(2,0) = maria maria_s2 0.0 ted ted_i_p2 0.0 ted ted_o_p2 0.0
path(3,0) = maria maria_s3 0.0 ted ted_i_p3 0.0 ted ted_o_p3 0.0
path(0,0) = maria maria_s0 0.0 ted ted_i_p0 0.0 ted ted_o_p0 0.0
path(10,0) = susan susan_s0 0.0 peter peter_i_p0 0.0 peter peter_o_p0 0.0
path(1,0) = maria maria_s1 0.0 ted ted_i_p1 0.0 ted ted_o_p1 0.0
```

is not unsorted. May be you want see the indexes by numeric orders.

```
path(Number,0)
```

then Number is Order! not value! Yes, It's a Index!!

Path always order by `Number` called index! idependent of input order, shown order whatever...

I've never heard about sorting indexes!